# Use stereo 3.5mm microphone with MacBook Pro headset socket

Tags: audio, microphone

I have a **stereo** condenser mic that I've had for a long time and I quite like it - [here's the specific model](https://www.sony.com/electronics/support/audio-video-accessories-microphones/ecm-ms907/manuals) (*Sony Electret Stereo Condenser mic, model ECM-MS907*).  I'd like to be able to use it for recording with my MacBook Pro ([15-inch 2019 model](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP794)), which has four USB-C ports and one 3.5mm combined headphone-and-mic socket.

As noted [all](https://www.musiconerd.com/single-post/How-to-use-an-external-mic-on-a-Macbook-Pro-2019) [over](https://www.zdnet.com/article/how-do-i-connect-a-microphone-to-my-macbook/) [the](https://www.macworld.com/article/1167452/external-mic-macbook-air.html) [internet](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7628872), one does not simply plug the 3.5mm mic plug into the 3.5mm socket and achieve microphone happiness.  [The plug is TRS and the socket is TRRS](https://www.cablechick.com.au/blog/understanding-trrs-and-audio-jacks/), and if the MBP isn't happy with what it's sensing, it doesn't offer the mic as an input device.

[Wishfully] thinking there was a universal standard for these things, I purchased [a mic/headphone splitter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004SP0WAQ) (*in case that link goes away - the description is "StarTech.com Headset Adapter, Microphone and Headphone Splitter - 3.5mm Male Aux to 3.5mm Female Audio & Mic Combo Jack Y Cable for Laptop / PC (MUYHSMFF)"*) and plugged my mic into the headphone side of the y-adapter.  The result is **BAD**.  The mic audio is faintly detectable in the background, but mostly what I hear is the extremely loud flopping around of some bad connection (ground-fault?) that's either destroying my equipment or acting out a reasonable facsimile thereof.  Waveform:

[image]

I think the issue I'm having is that this is a **stereo** mic, with a TRS connection of (I think) Left-Right-Ground, but most mics are mono, with a TS connection of Audio-Ground.  I have no hypothesis about *why* this leads to the particular badness I'm seeing/hearing, though.

So the question is: is there some adapter or configuration that will allow me to use this analog stereo input source?

A good starting place: does anyone know the actual capabilities of the audio socket on this model MBP?  The specs on Apple's website simply say:

[image]

BTW, if I figure out how to get it working for my MBP audio port, I think chances are good that it'll also work for my iPhone, using the lightning-to-3.5mm adapter.

**UPDATE:**

Some of the comments suggest that MBPs can't do stereo input; I don't think that's categorically the case, as [this Apple page](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/about-audio-ports-cpmh0052/mac) says, for example, "Audio in: You can use this port to connect stereo equipment to your Mac with a stereo miniplug-to-RCA cable adapter."  It's very unclear to me what capabilities my model of MPB actually has, though.

Comment: Preëmptively, to any moderators: before voting to close this issue as a duplicate of the many other questions about microphone inputs, please note that this question is particular to **stereo** input, which seems to be causing the particular problem.

Comment: The Mac has no option for stereo mic input. I think you're going to have to get a USB mic preamp, but I'd need to check the mic's spec… if it's high impedance, a matched interface may be hard to source.

Comment: Yeah, high impedance, won't match any standard mic preamp - https://www.sony.com/electronics/support/res/manuals/W000/W0004150M.pdf Another factor will be if you're going to be using this for consumer-level audio, very few apps will accept a stereo input as a mic. You might be better off just getting a dedicated USB mic.

Comment: Quick look at Sweetwater says variable impedance mic pres start at $100, a cheap USB mic would be maybe half that. https://www.sweetwater.com/store/search.php?s=variable+impedance+mic+pre

Comment: I wouldn’t be so concerned about mods shutting down the question, as it is a very thought out in-depth question :). I do wonder if there is another stackexchange page that may be able to advise you better about the different compatibilities of TRS and TTRS input/outputs, but you seem to know a bit about it already. It is still perfectly fine to ask it here of course.

Comment: Sadly, I do not know a lot about this stuff, but if there is any contribution I can make, I know some apps (eg quicktime) can use an iPhone’s microphone when it is plugged into the Mac. This may be of some use to you but I suspect it would be limited to Apple's own software and may not provide the sound quality you desire. Best of luck solving your problem!

Comment: @AVelj - you can't physically map this mic's pinouts to a Mac headphone socket because even if you made up your own cable, you still would have nothing for the second mic to connect to. The Mac's mic input is mono - as far as I'm aware pretty much all computer mic inputs are mono, they're for consumer-level headsets, not tricsky mid-side mics. Finding the pinouts is trivial… but knowing them still doesn't help.

Comment: In fact then finding consumer software that knows how to process mid-side might be another issue, you cannot process mid side as regular left & right, it doesn't work that way, it uses a phase inversion technique to generate the stereo image.

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm not actually certain whether the output of the mic is mid-side, or whether it's left-right (i.e. the conversion from mid-side is done inside the mic).  Even if it's the former, though, I could do the stereo processing using Audacity or similar by using the appropriate transform.

Comment: @KenWilliams I came across your question and, surprising, ran into a very similar problem: TRS mic (Lavalier mic, I think stereo) to Macbook Pro usb-c model. I purchased the exact same splitter and my laptop would not recognize the mic, only the headphone split. Luckily, my mic came with a TRS to TRRS adapter that does work well. This adapter should be using grounded headphone lines (still detected by the driver) with mono "Sleeve" mic input. I think the correct wiring should be mapping "TR" from stereo mic to "S" mono-mic of laptop input TRRS. Not sure about wiring for the splitter.